# Zip function and going through lists that incorporates raw_input?

Tags: python

Can zip be used to go through question and answer variables that ask for raw input in the answer variable?

Comment: Maybe. A list/sequence of questions could be zipped with a list/sequence of answers that could then be iterated over. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do something like this, but i wouldn't suggest it:

```
questions = ['Question 1? ', 'Question 2? ']
answers = [input(questions[0]), input(questions[1])]

zip_object = zip(questions, answers)
```

The answers variable will be filled by your answers.